# Windows Media Player playlist

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, playlist, windows-media-player

I am using VS2012 VB.net.

I am using the Windows Media Player control via code. I have a currentPlaylist that has multiple media items associated with it.

My question is this: How can I play the next item in the playlist? I have had a look at the documentation on the internet with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer:

```
MediaPlayerObject.controls.next()
```